# Qt Singleton implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I was looking for a Singleton Qt implementation and found [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_thread-safe_singleton). but I have some question about it.

1. What is the purpose of making `create` a `QBasicAtomicPointer` ?
2. What is the point in `qCallOnce` of using `testAndSetRelaxed` if previously we have used fetchAndStoreAcquire ? Isn't the acquire semantic already preventing any memory reordering after it ?
3. What is the purpose of the `qCallOncePerThread` function ? Isn't `qCallOnce` already thread-safe ?

I copy the contents of the suggested implementation here:

call_once.h

```
#ifndef CALL_ONCE_H
#define CALL_ONCE_H

#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QAtomicInt>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QThreadStorage>
#include <QThread>

namespace CallOnce {
    enum ECallOnce {
        CO_Request,
        CO_InProgress,
        CO_Finished
    };

    Q_GLOBAL_STATIC(QThreadStorage<QAtomicInt*>, once_flag)
}

template <class Function>
inline static void qCallOnce(Function func, QBasicAtomicInt& flag)
{
    using namespace CallOnce;

#if QT_VERSION < 0x050000
    int protectFlag = flag.fetchAndStoreAcquire(flag);
#elif QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    int protectFlag = flag.fetchAndStoreAcquire(flag.load());
#endif

    if (protectFlag == CO_Finished)
        return;
    if (protectFlag == CO_Request && flag.testAndSetRelaxed(protectFlag,
                                                           CO_InProgress)) {
        func();
        flag.fetchAndStoreRelease(CO_Finished);
    }
    else {
        do {
            QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
        }
        while (!flag.testAndSetAcquire(CO_Finished, CO_Finished));
    }
}

template <class Function>
inline static void qCallOncePerThread(Function func)
{
    using namespace CallOnce;
    if (!once_flag()->hasLocalData()) {
        once_flag()->setLocalData(new QAtomicInt(CO_Request));
        qCallOnce(func, *once_flag()->localData());
    }
}

#endif // CALL_ONCE_H
```

singleton.h

```
#ifndef SINGLETON_H
#define SINGLETON_H

#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QScopedPointer>
#include "call_once.h"

template <class T>
class Singleton
{
private:
  typedef T* (*CreateInstanceFunction)();
public:
  static T* instance(CreateInstanceFunction create);
private:
  static void init();

  Singleton();
  ~Singleton();
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(Singleton)
  static QBasicAtomicPointer<void> create;
  static QBasicAtomicInt flag;
  static QBasicAtomicPointer<void> tptr;
  bool inited;
};

template <class T>
T* Singleton<T>::instance(CreateInstanceFunction create)
{
  Singleton::create.store(create);
  qCallOnce(init, flag);
  return (T*)tptr.load();
}

template <class T>
void Singleton<T>::init()
{
  static Singleton singleton;
  if (singleton.inited) {
    CreateInstanceFunction createFunction = (CreateInstanceFunction)Singleton::create.load();
    tptr.store(createFunction());
  }
}

template <class T>
Singleton<T>::Singleton() {
  inited = true;
};

template <class T>
Singleton<T>::~Singleton() {
  T* createdTptr = (T*)tptr.fetchAndStoreOrdered(nullptr);
  if (createdTptr) {
    delete createdTptr;
  }
  create.store(nullptr);
}

template<class T> QBasicAtomicPointer<void> Singleton<T>::create = Q_BASIC_ATOMIC_INITIALIZER(nullptr);
template<class T> QBasicAtomicInt Singleton<T>::flag = Q_BASIC_ATOMIC_INITIALIZER(CallOnce::CO_Request);
template<class T> QBasicAtomicPointer<void> Singleton<T>::tptr = Q_BASIC_ATOMIC_INITIALIZER(nullptr);

#endif // SINGLETON_H
```

How to use

```
// myclass.h

#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    MyClass(QObject* parent = 0);
    static MyClass* createInstance();
public:
    ~MyClass();
    static MyClass* instance();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H


// myclass.cpp

#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <QObject>
#include "singleton.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject* parent):
 QObject(parent)
{
}

MyClass* MyClass::createInstance()
{
    return new MyClass();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

MyClass* MyClass::instance()
{
    return Singleton<MyClass>::instance(MyClass::createInstance);
}

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include "myclass.h"

#define MyClassInstance Singleton<MyClass>::instance()

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QTextStream(stdout) << MyClass::instance()->metaObject()->className() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the two words "suggestion" and "singleton" usually dont go well together in a question. I would suggest you to not use a singleton :P

Comment: Do you really need lazy loading of singleton? Because such workaround was provided only for compatibility with C++03 and lower. If you are using C++11, singleton may be created in 2 lines of code.

Comment: Not really. I'd appreciate if you could point me to the reasons for that workaround.

Comment: @perencia reason is simple: more than one thread tries to access an instance in same time and there were possible a situation, when singleton was created twice.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is will be enough to use next singleton implementation. As I remember, C++11 gurantees that there will be only one instancing/initialization for a static variable.
Original problem was in case, when more than one thread tries to access an instance in same time and there were possible a situation, when singleton was created twice.

```
template <typename T, typename D = T>
class Singleton
{
    friend D;
    static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<T, D>, "T should be a base type for D");

public:
    static T& instance();

private:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
    Singleton( const Singleton& ) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& ) = delete;
};

template <typename T, typename D>
T& Singleton<T, D>::instance()
{
    static D inst;
    return inst;
}

// Usage:
class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass>
{
public:
    void foo(){}
};

// Access: 
MyClass::instance().foo();
```

Comment: The `D` is to allow the wrapped class to be used polymorphically ?

Comment: @perencia yes. It's a template from my utils.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov Why need to be `<typename T, typename D = T>` instead of single `T`?

Comment: @Jiu as mentioned in above comment - it is for polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it, `D` is a sub class and `T` is the parent. if mention `D` only create an instance of `D` and return as `T` in `instance()`

Comment: This looks like an interesting answer, but there is little explanation.  Can you explain what your code does? why T and D ?  Need a lot more info

Comment: @TSG this code is an implementation of a singleton pattern. T and D if you want to provide only base interface for delivered class.

Answer (score 0):

Main concept of using **Singleton** pattern is to restrict the instantiation to certain number of objects, in common use to one.

Q1 : Atomic pointer

Atomic operations are done without interruption , so handled multi-thread instance calls.

Q2 : point of qCallOnce

This function checks if any other threads are executing and if so wait for CO_finished flag in

```
    do {
             QThread::yieldCurrentThread();
       }
    while (!flag.testAndSetAcquire(CO_Finished, CO_Finished));
```

Q3 : point of qCallOncePerThread

```
 if (!once_flag()->hasLocalData()) {
        once_flag()->setLocalData(new QAtomicInt(CO_Request));
```

I think to handle LocalData of singleton class per each thread instacnes

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for more in-depth answers. Let me clarify. Q1. I understand the `flag` variable being an atomic to make `qCallOnce` thread-safe, but why the `create` variable ? I don't see any benefit for that specific variable. Q2. I was asking specifically for the `testAndSetRelaxed` after a `testAndSetAcquire`.