# singleton implementation via macro or template in C++

Tags: c++11, singleton

After referred [Qt Singleton implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172607/qt-singleton-implementation). I got two solutions:

The first, using `template`:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton
{
    friend T;
public:
    static T& instance();

private:
    Singleton() = default;
    ~Singleton() = default;
    Singleton( const Singleton& ) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=( const Singleton& ) = delete;
};

template <typename T>
T& Singleton<T>::instance()
{
    static T inst;
    return inst;
}

class SingletonTest : public Singleton<SingletonTest>
{
public:
    void foo(){
        qDebug()<<"FOO"<<this;
    }
};
```

The second using `macro`:

```
#define SingletonClass(className) \
public: \
    className(className const&)         = delete; \
    className& operator=(className const&)    = delete; \
    static className& instance() { \
        static className instance; \
        return instance; \
    } \
private: \
    className() = default; \
    ~className() = default;

class SingletonTest
{
    SingletonClass(SingletonTest)
public:
    void foo(){
        qDebug()<<"FOO"<<this;
    }
};
```

About the first one, it allows instance creation like `SingletonTest t`, as a Singleton class I think that should not be allowed.
Then I think about the second one, it solves the first problem, but it has to pass the class name into the macro.

- So which implementation is better?
- Anyway to avoid passing the class name?
- Is that wrong to return pointer of `instance()` function?

Comment: Templates are always preferred over macros except where you realllly need some template naming magic, and even then I would put the minimum possible inside the macro.

Comment: @GemTaylor I am trying to make Singleton reduce code redundancy. if a class indicate as the singleton automatically remove public constructors and provide `instance()` function.

Comment: Ok, so I have whacked the first comment as "initial reaction". Perhaps the trick is for the singleton to instance a wrapper class. That way the implementation class can declare protected constructors?